# Button desempenhando o mesmo papel da seta do browser

Tags: html

Gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de um `button` fazer o mesmo papel da seta "voltar" do browser ? Voltar para a página anterior sem dar refresh na página ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, desta forma:

```
<input type = 'button' value = "Voltar" onclick = 'javascript:history.back(-1)'>
```

Comment: E num `input type="submit"` fazer igual, manter no mesmo local a página anterior porém dar o refresh ?

Comment: onclick = 'NOME_DA_SUA_PAGINA.html'

Comment: Assim ela da refresh e volta ao topo da página não teria algum jeito de dar refresh e manter no mesmo local que estava ?

Comment: Se você quer voltar em algum ponto especifico de um formulário, coloque um autofocus nos atributos do campo. Fora isso, sempre que a página for aberta ele vai carregar o inicio dela.